# Product identity: $x^{n+1}-1=\prod_{k=0}^{n}{(x-e^\frac{2ik\pi}{n+1}})$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, products, pochhammer-symbol

I recently stumbled upon this equation and frankly, I have no idea where this identity comes from. I tried to plot the two sides of the identity as a function and surprisingly, this equation holds. Wolfram Alpha hints that this has something to do with a “q-Pochhammer symbol”, but I have never heard of that before.
$$x^{n+1}-1=\prod_{k=0}^{n}{(x-e^{\frac{2ik\pi}{n+1}})}{}$$
Does anyone know this identity and how do you prove it without difficult math? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well its $n+1$ roots of $1$.

Comment: Thats not pochhammer, its product $\prod$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

By the [foundamental theorem of algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra) $$x^{n+1}-1=0$$

hase exactly $n+1$ [roots on complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity), given by

$$x=e^{\frac{2k\pi i}{n+1}}$$

for $k=0,...,n$.

Then recall that a polynomial can be factorized by its roots $r_i$

$$p_n(x)=(x-r_1)(x-r_2)...(x-r_n)$$

Answer (score 1):

By [fundamental theorem of algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra) any monic polynomial $P_n(x)$ of degree $n$ can be represented as:
$$
P_n(x)=\prod_{k=1}^n (x-x_k),
$$
where $x_k$ are the roots of the polynomial.

In your case the roots of the polynomial $x^{n+1}-1$ are $x_k=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{n+1}k}$ with $k=0..n$.