# Product over Dirichlet characters mod n

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I've recently learned about Dirichlet characters and am trying to develop a better understanding of the structure of characters mod n. Here's a problem that's kept me occupied for a bit:

Expand the following product into a polynomial with integer coefficients.

$\prod_{\chi \mod 9} (x-\chi(2))$.

My first approach was to use brute force (i.e. we know the values of all 6 characters mod 9. We can plug the values of these characters at 2 in and evaluate the polynomial.) But this has proven to be pretty tedious, and I'm wondering if there's some way we can capitalize on the fact that 2 is a primitive root mod 9?

Apologies if this is a trivial question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are $\phi(N)$ characters $\bmod N$. If $a$ has order $k$ in $\Bbb{Z/NZ}^\times$ then $k|\phi(N)$ and $$\prod_{\chi\bmod N} (x-\chi(a))=\prod_{m=0}^{k-1}(x-e^{2i\pi m/k})^{\phi(N)/k}= (x^k-1)^{\phi(N)/k}$$

Comment: Thank you! Very clear explanation.

Answer (score 0):

reuns's answer is certainly correct. But I think a few comments on the equation below can be helpful.

$$\prod_{\chi\bmod N} (x-\chi(a))=\prod_{m=0}^{k-1}(x-e^{2i\pi m/k})^{\phi(N)/k}= (x^k-1)^{\phi(N)/k}$$

The first equality makes intuitive sense. It is also easy to show that $\chi(a) = e^{2\pi i m/k}$ for some $m$. But we still need to prove that the set of $\phi(N)$ characters can be divided into $\phi(N)/k$ subsets, each of which is made of $k$ characters, each of which gives us, acting on $p$, $e^{2\pi i m/k}$ with a distinct $m = 0, 1, \dots, k-1$.

For brevity, we denote $\Bbb{Z/NZ}^\times$ as $G$. We notice that $\{p^n\}$ forms a subgroup $H$ of order $k$. Since the group is Abelian, normality is not a problem. So the cosets $G/H$ forms another group. It is then easy to show that characters on $G$ is simply the direct product of characters on $H$ and characters on $G/H$, defined in the obvious way.

The second equality is explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2725046/product-identity-xn1-1-prod-k-0nx-e-frac2ik-pin1).